504 gateway timeout error when bigquery is performing slowly
Context: I am naive developer. My team has an array of services deployed in k8lens. 2 services are there, service_1, service_2. service_1 is a fullstack jhipster spring-boot  and react app for internal purpose and service_2 is an apache-camel spring boot based microservice. service_1 communicates with service_2 using grpc call.
Issue: Everyday from 9-11 am IST, bigquery is down for us. During this time when we query from service_1, then request flows till service_2, job gets submitted to BQ and then after around 2-3 mins response is available with service_2 which it sends back (via the grpc response) to service_1 which then should render on frontend (response of the http get call).
But it is not rendering it on frontend and before that only gateway timeout error 504 is comming.
On the frontend code, i have set the timeout of 1400 sec (verified from the request object sent via axios), on the backend it sends a grpc call to the service_2 and gets response after 2-3 mins (verified from the logs)
Only during the mentioned hours, when BQ is slow for us, the frontend gives 504 error. but the response is still comming as we can see on the logs of service_1 and service_2.
I tried to reproduce this error on my local, by putting thread.sleep(300_000) in backend code as well as multiple breakpoints on frontend. Frontend still renders the response even when the response comes at a delay of more than 30 mins. but on production it gives timeout 504 issue.
What could be the error ? how to resolve this ?
Things I have verified:

Frontend does set the timeout of around 1400 secs.
backend gets the response from the service_2.
but frontend gives 504 error only in prod during the mentioned hours.

more context: 2 instances of both the service is deployed on k8lens. jhipster uses undertow as its server.

Is it correct to say that "BQ is slow for [you]"? IIUC the backend log entry that you included shows that BigQuery respond to the request in 0.3 seconds. The issue appears to be that "user-journey" returns a HTTP 504 (even though the backend gRPC succeeded). The diagram suggests "spring boot" to "user journey" is gRPC but the 504 that you included suggests this is actually HTTP/REST. It seems that you should investigate what's going wrong with "user journey" during this time period.

@DazWilkin as per i can see, the request goes to userjourney @4:50:45 and response comes from it @4:52:58 . Please correct me if I am understanding it wrongly. Also, as per the daily observation, BQ seems to be down for our team at the mentioned timelines, but the emphasis here is it takes around 2-3 mins to respond and during this my service_1 gives stream_timeout_error.

Folks, we were finally able to resolve this. It was a load-balancer timeout issue. it was set to 30 sec, that's why timeout was comming. The load-balancer was behind the service_1.
